# Count Clicks in excel

Tags: excel, count

Can some one recommend any free program which counts the number of clicks Clicked inside a cell.

For Example Imagine something like Spreadsheet
I click on A1 cell the value shows 1
Then I click A1 cell again the value shows 2 and so on
If I click A3 cell somewhere in between the click count on Cell A3 shows 1 and so on

If something like this can be achieved as a macro with in excel (2003 please) please suggest or any other free program that you might be aware about, please do let me know. I appreciate all your help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you define the target to certain area A1:L29? this code selects the entire sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel doesn't have a worksheet event for the mouse left click.

It does have an event for 'SelectionChange' and this can be combined with an API call to check if the left mouse button was clicked.

This code needs to go into the Sheet Object in the Project Explorer area for the worksheet that you are targeting.

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer

Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Key As Integer

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
''//If multiple cells selected with left click and drag
''// then take no action

Key = GetKeyState(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN)

If Key And 1 Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
''//Check to see if cell contains a number, before
''// trying to increment it
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Resize(1, 2).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
''//Resize the selection, so that if the cell is clicked
''// for a second time, the selection change event is fired again
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Although this code works, it can increment a cell value even if the user has not left clicked their mouse.

---

I would recommend using the 'BeforeDoubleClick' event instead if possible.  This is built into Excel and is more reliable than the code above.

In order to increment a cell value, the user would need to double click on the cell.

This code needs to go into the Sheet Object in the Project Explorer area for the worksheet that you are targeting.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
''//Check to see if cell contains a number, before
''// trying to increment it
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Resize(1, 2).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
''//Resize the selection, so that if the cell is clicked
''// for a second time, the selection change event is fired again
        Cancel = True
''//Stop the cell going into edit mode
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow awesome, this serves my need. Thanks a lot.